# React native Android fade animation flashing in loop

Tags: android, react-native

In React Native 0.61, I've got a pulse animation happening. It works properly on iOS, but not on Android.

Here's the code:

```js
  state = {
fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(1),
springValue: new Animated.Value(0),
  };

  runPulseAnimation() {
Animated.loop(
  Animated.parallel([
    Animated.timing(this.state.springValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      friction: 3,
      tension: 40,
      duration: 1500,
    }),
    Animated.timing(this.state.fadeAnim, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 1500,
    }),
  ]),
).start();
  }
```

The loop happens properly, however on Android, right after the animation ends, opacity switches back to 1 before the spring value resets. Again, this doesn't happen on iOS.

Anyone run into something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it. Instead of starting with 1, and fading to 0, since the beginnging of my view is hidden behind another view with opacity 1, I was able to sequence the animations and fade in and out and start the fadeAnim at 1.

```js
  state = {
    fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0),
    springValue: new Animated.Value(0),
  };
```

```js
    let fadeInAndOut = Animated.sequence([
      Animated.timing(this.state.fadeAnim, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 750,
      }),
      Animated.timing(this.state.fadeAnim, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 750,
      }),
    ]);

    Animated.loop(
      Animated.parallel([
        fadeInAndOut,
        Animated.timing(this.state.springValue, {
          toValue: 1,
          friction: 3,
          tension: 40,
          duration: 1500,
        }),
      ]),
    ).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the default value does not seem to be initialized.
Would you like to try this if what you're trying to do is a repetitive task?

```js
      runPulseAnimation() {
        this.state.fadeAnim.setValue(1)
        this.state.springValue.setValue(0)

      Animated.parallel([
        Animated.timing(this.state.springValue, {
          toValue: 1,
          friction: 3,
          tension: 40,
          duration: 1500,
        }),
        Animated.timing(this.state.fadeAnim, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 1500,
        }),
      ]).start(() => this.runPulseAnimation());
      }
```

Comment: Thanks. The .loop resets the values. I tested your code, and got a similar result.